# Making Zipcode optional for only 1 website

Tags: magento2, magento2-enterprise

Magento2 How can we make zip code optional for only 1 website? I know we can make it optional for entire site.

I have multi-website & want to make is optional for only 1 website. I am using cloud enterprise version

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Store** –> **Configuration** -> **Select your Store**
[image: Store Select]

After That Go to **General** –> **Country Options** (In Same Store Configuration Page)
[image]

That’s it! Now during frontend checkout, Magento 2 will no longer ask your customer for zip code in selected countries as shown below.
[image]

For More Read Reference : https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-make-zip-postal-code-optional-for-checkout-in-magento-2

Comment: Please check the option of disabling zip code is not there for store & website